# upload failing when using special character

Tags: qt, amazon-s3

when I am using filename with special characters like "r(.mp3" or "r,.mp3".

```
why its failing to upload on amazons3.
```

Comment: That's hard to tell without more details. Which code are you using for uploading? What's the error message returned? etc.

Comment: thanks for reply I searched on this and i think most servers not allow special characters filename to upload